# C# Open New form from ComboBox.SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

am working on a field Application
i have a combobox with list of 13 options and a button, i want when the user clicks on an option and hits the button, a new form should open, but with what i have whenever the user clicks an option, nothing happens it just act as a void Expression but the program keeps on runnign without crashing.
i know there is a problem with this code snippet, someone should help

.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        switch (comboBox1.SelectedText)
        {
            case "INPUTS PER HEAD LAYER  PRODN (250 for 15 Months)":
                this.Hide();
                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.Show();
                break;
            case "CROP INPUTS PER HA RICE":
                this.Hide();
                Form3 f3 = new Form3();
                f3.Show();
                break;
            case "CROP INPUTS PER HA CASSAVA":
                this.Hide();
                Form4 f4 = new Form4();
                f4.Show();
                break;
            case "CROP INPUTS PER HA COCOA":
                this.Hide();
                Form5 f5 = new Form5();
                f5.Show();
                break;

            case "CROP INPUTS PER HA OIL PALM":
                this.Hide();
                Form6 f6 = new Form6();
                f6.Show();
                break;
            case "CROP INPUTS PER HA PLANTAIN/BANANA":
                this.Hide();
                Form7 f7 = new Form7();
                f7.Show();
                break;
            case "INPUTS PER UNIT HETROCLARIAS (500 FOR 6 MONTHS":
                this.Hide();
                Form8 f8 = new Form8();
                f8.Show();
                break;
            case "Inputs per Unit of Tilapia Fish(500 for 6mths)":
                this.Hide();
                Form9 f9 = new Form9();
                f9.Show();
                break;
            case "Cash INPUTS PER TON OF PALM FRUITS":
                this.Hide();
                Form10 f10 = new Form10();
                f10.Show();
                break;
            case "Cash INPUTS PER TON OF CASSAVA INTO GARRI":
                this.Hide();
                Form11 f11 = new Form11();
                f11.Show();
                break;
            case "Cash INPUTS PER TON OF PADDY INTO MILLED RICE":
                this.Hide();
                Form12 f12 = new Form12();
                f12.Show();
                break;
            case "Cash INPUTS for PROCESSING A TON OF FISH":
                this.Hide();
                Form13 f13 = new Form13();
                f13.Show();
                break;
            case "Honey Production Operating or Maintenance Cost":
                this.Hide();
                Form14 f14 = new Form14();
                f14.Show();
                break;
        }
```

Comment: do you know `if` or `switch` keyword in c#?

Comment: yes. i tried if and it said i couldnt convert a string to bool, i converted it and the program crashed

Comment: could you please trace your code and tell to me witch line trow that crash?

Comment: `comboBox1.selectedText = "INPUTS PER HEAD LAYER  PRODN (250 for 15 Months)":
                this.Hide();
                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.Show();
           
          If (bool.parse(ComboBox.SelectedText = "CROP INPUTS PER HA RICE) == true) {
                this.Hide();
                Form3 f3 = new Form3();
                f3.Show();}`

Comment: what do mean by `bool.parse(ComboBox.SelectedText = "CROP INPUTS PER HA RICE)`??? why you pars the value?  just use `ComboBox.SelectedText = "CROP INPUTS PER HA RIC"`

Comment: ant the code that you say dont exist in question!!!!!

Comment: yea i Re- edited the question to suit a someone that gave a reply

Comment: if i dont parse it, it will tel me cannot implicitly convert type string to bool

Comment: if you can just help me with the correct code, i would appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a condition to check which item in the `ComboBox` the user selected. One option is a `switch` and the code could be look like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(comboBox1.SelectedText)
    {
        case "INPUTS PER HEAD LAYER  PRODN (250 for 15 Months)":
            this.Hide();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            break;
        case "CROP INPUTS PER HA RICE":
            this.Hide();        
            Form3 f3 = new Form2();
            f3.Show();
            break;
        case "Inputs per Unit of Tilapia Fish(500 for 6mths)":
            this.Hide();        
            Form4 f4 = new Form2();
            f4.Show();
            break;
        case "Cash INPUTS PER TON OF PALM FRUITS":
            this.Hide();        
            Form5 f5 = new Form2();
            f5.Show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Have a look at [The switch statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa664749(v=vs.71).aspx) for more information.

> The switch statement selects for execution a statement list having an
>   associated switch label that corresponds to the value of the switch
>   expression.

Comment: Have you debugged it? What are the possible value for `comboBox1.SelectedText` in your app?

Comment: whenever i run the application and after selecting from the drop down TEXT, and i click the button nothing happens. the combobox1, has 7 option

Comment: I understand what you are doing. But you need a condition to choose the form you want to show. I thought your `ComboBox` has different values where the user choose one. That's why I need to know the possible values to change the switch condition. Maybe it would help when you poste the code where you populate the `ComboBox`. But please not as a comment; edit your question instead.

Comment: yes the combo box has different values and i hhave editied the codde for all the values in the combo box, so the user has to choose 1 from it

Comment: Have you debugged the code? What is the of `comboBox1.SelectedText` when you want to show for example `Form2`?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code from:

```
switch(comboBox1.SelectedText)
```

to

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    switch(comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString())
```

Depending on how you are binding your comboBox, selectedText may be returning an empty string.